# Thymeleaf is not rendering HTML page after taking a redirection request from a post call

Tags: java, spring-boot, controller, thymeleaf, redirect

I have a requirement which requires me to redirect to a new URL from a post call. This is being done through URL redirection from post to a new get call. I am using `thymeleaf` to render `HTML`.

The problem is that, although the redirection (from post to get) is happening, the new HTML (in get call) is not being rendered.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/updateUser", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String updateUser(@RequestBody User user){
    /*validations*/
    return "redirect:/Table";
}


@RequestMapping(value = '/Table', method = RequestMethod.GET)
 public String updateTable(){
     return "newPage";
}
```

Even after successful redirection (confirmed from network call), **newPage.html** is not being rendered. I don't understand what is being done wrong here, there is no **ERROR** or **WARN** log either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out where I was wrong!!!

I was making post call via ajax which prevented the redirection. I made post call from form action and thinks worked well.

In case if you want to stick with ajax, it will require a redirection after successful post call to ensure proper redirection

```
$ajax{ 
  method : "POST",
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: // write redirection code here
}
```

I missed this detail while posting the question, so thought I'll set things straight.